# Saving data from dynamic form in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, dynamicform

I have been trying to save data from dynamic form in Laravel 5.3. But I cannot save it as array. The error shows

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given...

Form:

```
<select class="form-control-sm" name="client_id[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control-sm" name="amount[]">
```

Model:

```
protected $fillable = ['client_id', 'amount'];

public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
}
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $count = Client::count();

    $payment = Payment::create(['amount' => $request->amount,
                                 'client_id'  => $request->client_id,
                                 ]);
    $payment->save();

    return redirect()->action('PaymentController@index');
}
```

Please help on this. Thank you.

Comment: for which line you get the error?

Comment: @Onix I am not sure. It seems like the input type is string where it should have been array. I guess I need to store array through controller.

Comment: how you entering amount in input field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> you are submitting form with array of text fields and select box, try
>   below

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $count = Client::count();
    foreach( $request->client_id as $key=>$val){
    $payment = Payment::create(['amount' => $request->amount[$key],
                                 'client_id'  => $val,
                                 ]);
 }

 return redirect()->action('PaymentController@index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ty to create the record like this:

```
$payment = Payment::create($request->input);
```

And change you redirect action to this:

```
View::make('path/to/view/')
```

or just use just `back();`  just to test if it works